# Do I need VGA drivers?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, gpu

I bought the "ASRock H81 Pro BTC" [and on the drivers-website I saw a VGA driver](http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/H81%20Pro%20BTC/?cat=Download&os=Win8a64).

I have an Intel Xeon processor (no GPU unit like in the i7's) and I will soon get a GTX 970.
Is a VGA driver directly from Ashrock needed for my GTX? Or is downloading the NVidia driver enough?

I'm a bit confused since I didn't thought that there would be a VGA driver provided by the mainboard manufacturer. I'm not sure if NVidia maybe could need this driver for something like "internal communication" or something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your CPU doesn't have an integrated GPU, then you don't need any VGA drivers for it.

When you get your GTX 970, it's recommended to get the drivers directly from nVidia instead of the motherboard/non-reference card manufacturer, since they are always up-to-date.

The motherboard does not have an onboard GPU, some CPUs do (which are called APUs). The drivers you see on their website are the drivers for the Intel HD graphics you can find on Intel CPUs.

On [this page](http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/H81%20Pro%20BTC/?cat=CPU):

> The CPU with "*" without GPU integrated, when this kind of CPU is installed, a discrete VGA card is required.